# How to locate react CreatableSelect element using python selenium test

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to locate react **CreatableSelect** element in python selenium script and tried various ways using Xpath but still not able to simulate select option from existing dropdown menu and create new one.

Below is my html code for dropdown.

```
<CreatableSelect name="abc" id="abc" isClearable options={abc1}/>
```

Div element for **CreatableSelect**.

```
<div class=" css-2b097c-container" id="abc">
<div class=" css-yk16xz-control">
    <div class=" css-g1d714-ValueContainer">
        <div class=" css-1wa3eu0-placeholder">Select...</div>
            <div class="css-b8ldur-Input">
                <div class="" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <input autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="react-select-2-input" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="text" aria-autocomplete="list" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 2px; background: 0px center; border: 0px; font-size: inherit; opacity: 1; outline: 0px; padding: 0px; color: inherit;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 16px; font-family: &quot;FS Elliot Web Regular&quot;, &quot;FS Elliot Web Regular&quot;, Arial, arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class=" css-1hb7zxy-IndicatorsContainer">
<span class=" css-1okebmr-indicatorSeparator"></span>
    <div aria-hidden="true" class=" css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer">
        <svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="css-6q0nyr-Svg">
            <path d="M4.516 7.548c0.436-0.446 1.043-0.481 1.576 0l3.908 3.747 3.908-3.747c0.533-0.481 1.141-0.446 1.574 0 0.436 0.445 0.408 1.197 0 1.615-0.406 0.418-4.695 4.502-4.695 4.502-0.217 0.223-0.502 0.335-0.787 0.335s-0.57-0.112-0.789-0.335c0 0-4.287-4.084-4.695-4.502s-0.436-1.17 0-1.615z">
            </path>
        </svg>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <input name="abc" type="hidden" value=""></div>
```

Below is populated dropdown.

[image]

I have tried below options in my python script but nothing worked.

```
abc = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=' css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer']/*[name()='svg'][@class='css-6q0nyr-Svg']")
abc.click()
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-select-2-input"]')
input.send_keys("TEST")
time.sleep(5)
input.send_keys(keys.ARROW.DOWN)
input.send_keys(keys.ARROW_RETURN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write XPath like
`//div[@class='css-1wa3eu0-placeholder']//input`

```
input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-1wa3eu0-placeholder']//input");
input.send_keys("ABC")
input.send_keys(keys.TAB)
```

Please confirm the python syntax. I might have done any mistake. But logic should be correct. I am writing the same kind of script in C#.